# postgreSQL select additional columns that aren't used in aggregate function

Tags: database, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to write a query in PostgreSQL and I'm getting a little frustrated because it works in other database engines. I need to select the top 5 users from a given joins table like this:

```
SELECT users.*, 
       COUNT(deals.id) AS num_deals 
FROM users, deals 
WHERE deals.users_id = users.id 
GROUP BY users.id 
ORDER BY num_deals LIMIT 5;
```

I need the top 5 users. This code works in sqlite, mysql, etc, yet PostgreSQL refuses to select additional fields that aren't used in aggregate functions. I'm getting the following error:

```
PGError: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

How can I do this in PostgreSQL??

Comment: I do believe it works in MySQL and SQLite but the "etc" is wrong. No other database allows this. Those are the only two.

Comment: Actually, assuming that users.id is a PRIMARY KEY, it is *not* wrong. (Though MySQL for example does it both when it's right and when it's wrong). PostgreSQL 9.1 will support running this query the way it is written - since the GROUP BY is on the PRIMARY KEY, we can infer that all the other columns are functionally dependent on it.

Comment: @Magnus: I know that 9.1 will support this, but 9.1 is currently not available

Comment: @horse: absolutely true. But the statement that they are wrong is partially (though only partially) incorrect.

Comment: @MagnusHagander: Do you know why a PRIMARY KEY is required and not mere UNIQU-ness? I cannot imagine a case where uniqueness would not be good enough.

Comment: @A.H. You are right, either `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE NOT NULL` would suffice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try:

```
SELECT users.*, a.num_deals FROM users, (
    SELECT deal.id as dealid, COUNT(deals.id) AS num_deals 
    FROM deals 
    GROUP BY deal.id
) a where users.id = a.dealid
ORDER BY a.num_deals DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: +1 for a cross-dbms solution. But the comma after users in the first line is wrong and you should order by num_deals DESC

Comment: can't you remove the reference to the 'users' table in the subquery? that way it will only look at each table once.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You're correct about the ORDER BY.  ...and at first I thought you were correct about the comma in the first line, but I think it is actually correct (it's separating the users table from the subquery/`a` table)

Comment: @araqnid: I've implemented your suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: @Gerrat: ah, you are right about the comma. I'm not used to that old-style joins, I always use JOIN ... ON syntax. Sorry for the noise

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Quite alright...I really need to start using the JOIN...ON syntax.  ...finding it hard to retrain my mind...I can't even change from the perfectly-good "N-KB3" type of chess notation to the "new-fangled" Nf3!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that users.id IS a PK, then you can either

wait for 9.1

group by all fields

use an aggregate (i.e. max() ) on all fields

Comment: with use max() - it low speed

Comment: The use distinct on:
select distinct on (col1, col2) col1, col2, col3, col4 from yada;

Answer (score 2):

One other solution that works is to use all attributes implicitly in GROUP BY

Thus following will be final query

```
SELECT users.*, 
       COUNT(deals.id) AS num_deals 
FROM users, deals 
WHERE deals.users_id = users.id 
GROUP BY users.id, users.name, users.attrib1, ..., users.attribN
ORDER BY num_deals LIMIT 5;
```

If you are using framework like rails then you can implement this easily with Model.column_names function.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case of somebody wants ANSI-92 standard solution and doesn't like 'Oracle' way to join tables...

```
SELECT users.*, num_deals
FROM users
JOIN
  (SELECT deals.users_id as users_id, count(deals.users_id) as num_deals
   FROM deals
   GROUP BY deals.id) grouped_user_deals
ON grouped_user_deals.users_id = users.id
ORDER BY num_deals DESC
LIMIT 5;
```